# App not showing in search by keywords result list in Google Playstore

Tags: android, search, store, keyword, playback

Published an app on google playstore about 3 weeks ago.
This is the name:
Omicron QR Barcode Scanner, QR Generator
The link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qrcodereader.farrago
The following keywords can be found in the store list description: qr, barcode, scanner, reader, generator, maker, contact, code, creator.
Also added "Barcode scanner" as a tag in the Store Listing.

Yet, the app doesn't show up AT ALL in the search result list when searching by any of the above keywords(e.g qr, qr code, barcode, barcode reader, qr scanner, etc-it only shows up when seaching by "omicron qr").
Shouldn't all the keywords in the title and description be enough to make the search engine include my app in the results? Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @amin Why did you post that link? What's not clear in the way I described my issue?